# Jacoco.exec is not generated during Maven build to produce Jacoco reports

Tags: linux, windows, jacoco

I wrote the code in Linux, and when I moved it to a Windows system to build JaCoCo reports, it failed to generate jacoco.exec correctly. However, it didn't result in an error; it just didn't produce the JaCoCo report. Maven still built successfully.When I use a test file in a Windows environment to build, I can successfully generate JaCoCo reports. However, when I replace the file with one copied from a Linux system, it fails to generate the reports.

how to solve it，How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.